# Visual C#: Can't find correct relative width for listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, stackpanel

So I have a listbox and I'm trying to use a stackpanel inside as an item with a border. Now I want every item to be the same width as my listbox, which is anchored to the sides of the window. I found how to set the width relative to the parent but for some reason it turns out to be wider. Can't seem to figure out why. Picture below code of how it looks.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxSecrets" Margin="10,107,10,10" Background="{x:Null}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Orange" CornerRadius="2,2,2,2" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2">
                <StackPanel Background="White" 
                            Width="{Binding RelativeSource=
        {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
        AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},
        Path=ActualWidth}"
                            >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Totp}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image]

Comment: what happens if you remove `Width="{Binding RelativeSource= ...`? items should fit ListBox width

Comment: I added it to get them wide. If I don't they're only the size of the contents. Maybe that's due to the border?

Comment: i see. no, it is not Border, it is ListBox property. `<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ...` should improve it

Comment: @ASh Alright! That fixed it! Thanks man! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListBox.ActualWidth is too much for ListBoxItems. But ListBoxItems will use all available width if ListBox has `HorizontalContentAlignment` set to `"Stretch"`:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
```